# Ember LiveReload inside Kubernetes Pod

Tags: ember.js, kubernetes, livereload, minikube

I'm setting up a local Kubernetes cluster using Minikube and Xhyve as the VM driver on Mac OS.

I have gotten volume mounting from my laptop to the pod working (when I bash into my pod with `kubectl exec -it my-pod -- /bin/bash` I can see the files inside the pod update with my filesystem), but the Ember app running inside the pod never reflects the file changes. I have to destroy the deployment, rebuild, and redeploy in order to see file changes take effect.

In my Dockerfile I `EXPOSE` port 42000 as the live reload port and start the server using a `CMD` which simply runs `ember server --host 0.0.0.0 --live-reload-port 42000`.

Is there some trick I'm missing to get the LiveReload feature working with Kubernetes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the issue is minikube not detecting the time change, due to mounted file system. if you can login to pod and touch the filename, see its reloads

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's a bug in Minikube: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/1551